# BizTalk Reconfigure issue - can't setup group

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I have a 2 BizTalk server N1 and N2

Recently I have put both on high availability and was working fine.
Recently due to some issue I have to reconfigure, so I did unconfigure N1.
After that I am trying to connect N2 to BizTalk group but getting an error.

> Enterprise sso was configured (connected to existing group)

And when I try to configure group (connect to previous group I am getting an error)

> You have specified to join a BizTalk group that is pointing to a different Enterprise Single Sign-On (SSO) Master Secret Server.  You will need to re-configure the local Enterprise Single Sign-On to join to the same SSO system.

Answer (score 0):

If SSO was configured on N1 and N1 was completely unconfigured, there is no way to recover access to N2.

BizTalk requires access to the SSO system to which it was originally joined.  Unfortunately, there is no way around this.

You only option is to now unconfigure and N2 and create a new Group.  This time though, you should configure the Master Secret Server on the SQL computer.

Comment: N1 is still as it is. There i unconfigured N2, and now again trying to connect to that grp.

Comment: @AhmedNoozanAli "**so I did unconfigure N1**" Please clarify or update the question to reflect the true scenario.